# Indices Question grade A*

Tags: exponential-sum

I am a student and I am having difficulty with answering this question. I keep getting the answer wrong. Please may I have a step by step solution to this question so that I won't have difficulties with answering these type of questions in the future.

$$(4n)^{3/2}  =  8^{-1/3}$$

Find the value of $n$.

This is what I did:

$4n^{3/2}  =   \frac12$

I don'the know what to do next.

Thank you

Comment: Take the square on both sides of the equation. $16n^3=1/4\Rightarrow 4^2n^3=1/4\Rightarrow n^3=\frac{1}{4^3}$

Comment: How do you work out what n is

Comment: Take the third root on both sides. The equation can be also written as $n^3=\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^3$ because of $\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^3=\frac{1^3}{4^3}=\frac{1}{4^3}$

Comment: How do you take the root on both sides?

Comment: Calculating the root is the opposite of calculating the power. By taking the third root you neutralize the powers. $\sqrt[3]{n^3}=\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{4^3}}$ What do you get ?

Comment: 1/4 is the answer  to the cube root of 1/4^3

Comment: I agree to your solution :)

Comment: I think it is not necessary. Firstly a step by step solution has been already posted. And secondly if someone interested in the steps we (mostly I) made she/he can read the comments. But it is a good attitude that you think of other users.

Comment: @OliviaAage: what you did is not correct. The solutions which have been posted are solutions to what you did,but not go your original problem, since filling in 1/4 in your original problem would give 1 = 1/2 which is clearly not correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(4n)^{\frac 32} = 8^{\frac {-1}3}$

$4^\frac 32.n^{\frac 32} = (2^3)^{\frac {-1}3}$

$8.n^{\frac 32} = 2^{-1}$

$8n^{\frac 32} = \frac 12$

$n^{\frac 32} = \frac 1{16}$

$n^{\frac 32} = \frac 1{2^4}$

$n^{\frac 32} = 2^{-4}$

$n = 2^{-4.\frac 23}$

$n = 2^{\frac{-8}{3}}$

$n = \frac{1}{2^{\frac{8}{3}}}$

Comment: Thankyou for the alternative solution. Both solutions have helped me.

Comment: @projectilemotion is it correct now?

Answer (score 1):

We have:
$$(4n)^{3/2}=8^{-1/3}$$
Note that the left hand side of your first step is wrong, the $4$ must also be distributed.
$$4^{3/2}\cdot n^{3/2}=\frac{1}{2}$$
Giving:
$$8\cdot n^{3/2}=\frac{1}{2}$$
Dividing both sides by $8$:
$$n^{3/2}=\frac{1}{16}$$
Exponentiating both sides by $2/3$:
$$(n^{3/2})^{2/3}=\left(\frac{1}{16}\right)^{2/3}$$
$$n^{\frac{3}{2}\cdot \frac{2}{3}}=\left(\frac{1}{16}\right)^{2/3}$$
$$n=\left(\frac{1}{16}\right)^{2/3}$$
$$n=\frac{1}{16^{2/3}}=\frac{1}{2^{8/3}}=\frac{1}{4\times 2^{2/3}}$$